# process all excel files in a folder in a remote server in python

Tags: python, directory, xlrd

I need to write a program to process all excel files in a folder in a remote server in Python. To process an excel file on my computer, I use

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook( filename)
```

then process `book`
However, I don't know how to get an excel file on remote server to process. Please help me with that. And if it is possible, please show me how to get all the excel files in a folder in remote server. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which OS? Window/Linus/etc?

Comment: How the remote server share the files? FTP, SMB or etc?

Comment: This is nothing to do with xlrd or Excel files. Change "excel file" to "text file" and you've got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

excelfiles = []

for cwd, folders, files in os.walk(starting_directory):  # For file in starting_directory
    for filename in files:
        path = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        if os.path.splitext(path)[1].lower() == '.xls':  # If the file ends in '.xls'
            excelfiles.append(path)

for spreadsheet in excelfiles:
    process_spreadsheet(spreadsheet)
```

Comment: server's OS is Linux. My computer's OS is Mac OS X 10.8. remote server share file through SMB. @kuyan: how to set server's URL, username, password?  . Thanks a lot for your help.